# Enable_if problems

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use the SFINAE principle to check whether the instantiated template is a random access iterator. To do this, I used `std::enable_if`, but the compiler throws an error:

> Cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier

How can I fix it? I really need help to figure it out.

```cpp
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, RandomAccessIterator>::value>
void quick_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare compare) {
    sorting(first, last, 0, last - first - 1, compare);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues I see:

- You're writing `std::enable_if<>` instead of `std::enable_if<>::type`, which is probably not what you meant to do.
- (The cause of the error) You have two return types: `std::enable_if<>` and `void`. You can only have one return type.

`std::enable_if` has a second optional type parameter that is the the type of `std::enable_if<>::type`. This is set by default to `void` so your return type will already be `void` from `std::enable_if<>::type`. However since you're putting `enable_if` in the return type I'd recommend you explicitly specify that the return type be `void`.

So the solution to your issue would look something like this:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, RandomAccessIterator>::value,
    void
>::type quick_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare compare) {
    sorting(first, last, 0, last - first - 1, compare);
}
```

Alternatively you could use `std::enable_if` in a template parameter:

```
template <
    class RandomAccessIterator,
    class Compare,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, RandomAccessIterator>::value,
        std::nullptr_t
    >::type = nullptr
>
void quick_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare compare) {
    sorting(first, last, 0, last - first - 1, compare);
}
```

Comment: The usage of `enable_if_t` in the last example is not robust: the user can ignore it by passing a custom template argument to the last parameter; and it prevents the function from being overloaded based on different conditions. A better alternative is a non-type parameter: `std::enable_if_t<..., std::nullptr_t> = nullptr` (using `nullptr_t` ensures that the user can't generate different instantiations by passing different args).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the advice, I had never thought about that issue before. The `nullptr` method is definitely better, I've edited my answer to improve it :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the technical issues mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236800/65863), your approach will simply not work at all.

`std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag, RandomAccessIterator>::value` will never evaluate as true, because an iterator is not an iterator tag. You need to use tag dispatching via [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), not SFINAE, to determine if the iterators being passed in are random-access or not.

See the example on cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Try this instead:

```cpp
template<class Iter, class Compare>
void quick_sort_impl(Iter first, Iter last, Compare compare, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
    sorting(first, last, 0, last - first - 1, compare);
}

template<class Iter, class Compare>
void quick_sort(Iter first, Iter last, Compare compare) {
    quick_sort_impl(first, last, compare, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
}
```

This way, if you try to call `quick_sort()` with iterators that are not random access, you will get a compiler error due to a missing `quick_sort_impl()` overload for non-random iterator tags. If you want to implement sorting for other types of iterators, simply overload `quick_sort_impl()` for the other types of iterator tags as needed.